# Wordpress automatic redirection to different pages on each loading

Tags: wordpress, elementor

how can i set automatic redirection after a time count to different URL on each site loading in wordpress with or without plugin

i tried one method in which i acan only redirect to a single page.but need to redirect it to multiple page on each loading